# Adobe Digital Editions not opening after install in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: adobe, winetricks, ebooks

I need ADE because of DRM in the e-books I want to read because there is no Linux support. So I have installed and verified wine, installed and verified winetricks, created a 32 bit prefix and used winetricks to install ADE by right-clicking on the zip and choosing the installer. After installation ADE won't open. Trying to open winetricks gets a message:

> You are using a 64 bit wine prefix. Note that many verbs only install
> 32 bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems please retest
> in a clean 32 bit WINEPREFEX before opening a bug report.

I did create a 32 bit prefix, maybe it went into the wrong folder? I dunno. Trying to open ADE I get a wait icon then the cursor returns. Nothing, no error messages. I'm missing a step or something and I have no idea what. Any directions or advice? I have looked and read all I could find on the internet and nothing helps me get any further than I am now.